# Proof that for $2$ propositional formulas $F,G$ and $F \vDash G$, a formula $H$ exists with $F \vDash H$ and $H \vDash G$

Tags: logic

For clarification, the symbol $\vDash$ means that for any allocation $\beta(F) =1 $ we get $\beta(G)=1$. Often this is associated with semantically entails. Moreover, $H$ only contains variables of $F$ and $G$.

To show this, I was thinking using the canonical DNF of $F$. If $F \vDash G$, there must be one or more conjunctions of Variables of $F$, that are true in both $F$ and $G$. Since $G$ might have additional variables, the allocation of these additional variables is irrelevant, i.e. they are always true, otherwise $F \vDash G$ would not hold.

Would this be a proper start? Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: See [Craig's Interpolation Th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation)

Comment: Why can't we take $H=F$?

Comment: Because $H$ contains variables of $G$